# fatal error: json-c/json.h: No such file or directory

Tags: yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I bitbake my `foo.bb`

I don't know what to do to solve this problem, should I add something in RDEPENDS or DEPENDS?

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 8
| gcc -std=c99 -g -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -lndctl -ljson-c fis.c -o fis
| fis.c:24:10: fatal error: json-c/json.h: No such file or directory
|  #include <json-c/json.h>
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to your bb file. Try to build foo

DEPENDS = "json-c"

TARGET_LDFLAGS = "-ljson-c"

Comment: The makefile already passes `-ljson-c` so all that is needed is `DEPENDS`.

Answer (score 0):

`<json-c/json.h>` is provided by the recipe:

- **poky/meta/recipes-devtools/json-c**

In order to make its output available to your recipe at compile time, you should specify it as compile-time dependency using `DEPENDS`.

- **foo.bb** :

```bash
DEPENDS += "json-c"
```

For more info check [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-DEPENDS).